# follow path with finger to execute code

Tags: jquery

I have the following page set up, which detects the coordinates when the user touchstarts, touchmoves and touchends. I'm trying to build some sort of game which in which the user has to draw a star for some code to execute. How can I detect when say 11 points have been passed over for some code to execute:

This is the code thus far:

```
touchMe[0].ontouchstart = function(e) {        
    log.html("Touch Start");
    var touche= e.touches[0]; 
    //instead of e.clientX, in touch event we have to acess like this    e.touches[0].clientX.
    log.append("X :" + touche.clientX + "Y :" +touche.clientY);
    log.append("</br>");
}    

touchMe[0].ontouchmove = function(e) {       
   log.html("Touch Move");
    var touche= e.touches[0]; 
     //instead of e.clientX, in touch event we have to acess like this    e.touches[0].clientX.
    log.append("X :" + touche.clientX + "Y :" +touche.clientY);
    log.append("</br>");
}  

touchMe.bind("touchend", function(e) {
  log.html("LOG");
});
```

DEMO

http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/Projects-2014/xmas-game-2014/interaction5/